# Mysql insert as select with date_add 1 month

Tags: mysql

I have following data in mysql ,

```
+-------------+------------+---------+---------
| SERVER_NAME | LOGDATE    | CPU_AVG | CPU_MAX
+-------------+------------+---------+---------
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-05 |    0.63 |   17.14
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-06 |    0.50 |   15.00
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-07 |    0.75 |   16.02
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-08 |    0.66 |   17.03
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-09 |    0.69 |   18.00
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-10 |    0.57 |   16.00
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-11 |    0.74 |   14.20
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-12 |    0.45 |   22.50
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-13 |    0.60 |   19.03
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-14 |    0.43 |   17.30
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-15 |    0.66 |   18.20
| bkupxxxxx   | 2012-06-16 |    0.56 |   15.10
 .............................................
+-------------+------------+---------+---------
```

I want to select these data as seed and add the LOGDATE 1 month and insert back to into mysql. How can I use date_add function to achieve it.

Thanks!!

Comment: please tell us the flow of what you want to do, then post what you have tried.

Comment: I found the solution , thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename SET logdate = DATE_ADD(logdate , INTERVAL 1 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[DATE_ADD( )](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)** and `INSERT...SELECT` statement for that.

```
INSERT into tableName (ColName)
SELECT DATE_ADD(LOGDATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
FROM   myTableName
```